# CNN model using regularisation technique

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm required to write a build-cnn function where it builds all the layers in a convolutional neural network, but also including regularisation technique such as Dropout and Batch Normalization.

Basically, i can only experiment on one of the regularisation technique at a time, to see the difference of the performance between dropout and batch norm. Hence, when the model is created:

```
mynewmodel = MyModel(name="network", num_classes=len(classes), 
                     feature_maps = 32, keep_prob = 0.5, batch_norm = None, 
                     optimizer="adam",learning_rate = 0.001)
```

In the above, it is creating the model which **uses dropout** instead of **batch normalisation**. If the keep_prob value is **not 1**, then it uses dropout. Both dropout and batch norm could not be used at the same time.

The problem I'm facing now is in the build-cnn function which I'm only required to do,

```
def my_cnn(self,x,reuse = False, name):
    with tf.variable_scope(name, reuse=reuse):
        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2D(.....)
        if self.batch_norm != None: #if None then don't use batch normalization
             conv1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(...)

        if self.keep_prob != 1: #if 1 then don't use dropout
             conv1 = tf.nn.dropout(...)
```

Would it be right, if i include **if statement** for the **batch norm** and **dropout layer** in this case, depending on which regularisation technique is being used?

Since the keep_prob is 0.5, and batch_norm is None, then it will only create the dropout layer in the cnn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a beginner. I think maybe if you use `tf.nn.dropout`, you may do like this `drop_out=tf.nn.dropout(conv1,keep_prob)` , or use 'tf.nn.batch_normalization' not 'tf.layer.batch_normalization'. And I think using the `if statement` to decide which tec should be used is right.

Answer (score 0):

Batch normalization and dropout both are used to deal with overfitting and can be used together. Though that requires a lot of tweaking and testing. But for your purpose, **yes** ifs and elses should do the trick!

Also, since you are using tensorflow, I would recommend to use tensorboard for visualizing your layers and graphing out the model runs.